Can you provide a code example that demonstrates the difference between "uncaught exceptions" and "user uncaught exceptions" in VS Code's debugger?
In the Breakpoints-view of the debugger in VS Code, there are checkboxes for "uncaught exceptions" and "user uncaught exceptions". On a conceptual level I understood what they are supposed to do from this post. However, I couldn’t come up with a simple code example in Python where the debugger behaves differently based on which box I checked.
I couldn't find an example via Google, I couldn't find anything mentioned about this in the official documentation, ChatGPT couldn't give me correct example and I also couldn't create an example myself where there is a different behavior by the debugger. It is always the same behavior. Namely, that it breaks on any uncaught exception regardless of whether I checked "uncaught exceptions" or "user uncaught exceptions".
For example, I don't see a different behavior when there is an exception that comes from a library:
import math

math.log(-1)

Versus an exception that is created by the user:
class MyCustomException(Exception):
    pass

raise MyCustomException()

So basically, I just don’t get what the option “user uncaught exceptions” is for. Namely, I would assume that “user uncaught exceptions” are a subset of “uncaught exceptions”. Therefore, if I only check “user uncaught exceptions”, then the debugger should probably just break at that subset. But what is the debugger then supposed to do when an exception outside of that subset occurs? Would it just stop the debugging session?
I don’t see the point of that. So, the option “user uncaught exceptions” just seems superfluous to me.

I don't have vscode, but the distinction between user uncaught exception would have to be between your code and library code, right?    Which would mean vscode would need to understand where the line between the two is.

@MarcelWilson That’s also a question I asked myself. How would VS Code know if a specific line of code is from a library or from user code? So, maybe I thought “library code” would be all the code that one imports, and “user code” is simply the code from the file that one is currently debugging. But I also couldn’t get a working example with that.

It could use the context of imported libraries at the setup/pyproject level.  e.g. Exceptions raised in requests are library vs in raised your project code.  If it indeed does that, that seems handy.

As I stated in the comment above, I dont have vscode but I imagine it might be something like this:
def cause_exception():
    raise Exception("weeeeeee")


# caught user exception
try:
    cause_exception()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Caught user exception")


# uncaught user exception
cause_exception()


With this example I also get the same behavior regardless of checking “uncaught exceptions” or “user uncaught exceptions”. Namely, the debugger breaks at line 2 (where the exception is raised) and the function call comes from line 13 (the uncaught exception).

Yeah, sorry.  I have no idea then.  Doesn't seem like vscode worded things the way we are expecting.
